# How to get base path from Node js Side?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

**Note:** I tried all questions & answer related to this topic but am not able to resolve the issue.

**I want to base path from Node Js Side. Example below. I using [angular js + NodeJS/ExpressJS ]**

```
 <base href="/Tutorial/Routing/StateProvider/" />
```

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp2">
<title>Index | Angular Js</title>
<base href="/Tutorial/Routing/StateProvider/" />
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<!--<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.2/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="StateProviderController.js"></script>

<body >
<nav class="navbar navbar-default row">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="TutorialHome"> State Routing</a>
        </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a ui-sref="Profile">Profile</a></li><!--State Transition on click-->
                <li><a ui-sref="Account">Account</a></li><!--State Transition on click-->
                <li><a ui-sref="Setting">Setting</a></li><!--State Transition on click-->
                <li style="float: right;"><a ui-sref="Home">Home</a></li><!--State Transition on click-->
            </ul>

    </div>
</nav>
```

***Controller Js***

```
var myapp= angular.module('myapp2',["ui.router"]);
myapp.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider,$urlMatcherFactoryProvider){
    $urlMatcherFactoryProvider.strictMode(false);
    $stateProvider
        .state('TutorialHome', {
            url:'/index',
            templateUrl:'/index.html'
        })
        .state('Home',{
            url:'/',
            templateUrl:'http://localhost:3000/'
        })
        .state('Profile',{
            url:'/Profile',
            templateUrl:'Profile.html'
        })
        .state('Account',{
            url:'/Account',
            templateUrl:'Account.html'
        })
        .state('Setting',{
            url:'/Setting',
            templateUrl:'Setting.html'
        })
        .state('Setting.StudenListing', {
            url:'/StudenList',
            views: {
                'StudenListing': {
                    templateUrl: 'StudenListing.html',
                    controller:'StudentListingData'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('Setting.StudenListing.StudentList',{
            url:'/StudenList/:StudentID',
            /* templateUrl: 'StudentDetails.html',
            controller:'StudentDetails'*/
            views:{
               'StudentDetails': {
                   templateUrl: 'StudentDetails.html',
                   controller:'StudentDetails'
              }
            }
        })
    ;

   // $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/index');
 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

});
myapp.controller('StateProviderCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.message ="Welcome To State Provider Page";
});

myapp.controller('StudentListingData',function($scope,$http){
    console.log('test');
$http.get('/StudenRecordData').success(function(response){
   // console.log(response);
    $scope.StudentRecorddata =response;
})
});

myapp.controller('StudentDetails',function($scope,$http,$stateParams){
    $scope.StudentID = $stateParams.StudentID;
    //console.log( $scope.StudentID);

    $http.get('/StuentRecordSearch/'+ $stateParams.StudentID).success(function(response){
        //console.log(response);
        $scope.StuentDetails =response[0];
    })

});
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var url =require('url');

var index = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);

app.get('/*',function(req,res){
  console.log('node js request call');
  var pathname2 = url.parse(req.url);
  console.log('pathname-1:'+pathname2);
  console.log('pathname-2:'+__dirname);
  console.log('pathname-3:'+__filename);
  console.log(url.parse(index));
  //console.log('basw path:'+process.env.PWD);
  res.sendFile(path.resolve('public/index.html'));
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});



module.exports = app;
```

Comment: did you try req.path  see express api doc http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.path

Comment: i tried but get full path like `/Tutorial/Routing/StateProvider/Setting/StudenList/StudenList/2` .but i want to base path like `/Tutorial/Routing/StateProvider/`

Comment: rather than read HTML file and fetch base your 
Why not you just create JAD or other template and parse with you required base url
In this way you can handle it from nodejs rather than depend upda fron end file

Answer (score 2):

Use `cheerio` module for extracting the DOM at server side.

create `utility.js`

```js
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var fs = require('fs');

var utility = {
  getBasePath : function (filePath) {
    fs.readFile(filePath, function (err, html) {
      if (err) { throw err; }
      else {
        $ = cheerio.load(html.toString());
        return $('base').attr('href');   
      }
    });
  }
};

module.exports = utility;
```

update your `app.js`

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var url =require('url');

var index = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

var utility = require('./utility');  /// load your module

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);

app.get('/*',function(req,res){
  console.log('node js request call');
  
  var basePath = utility.getBasePath('./index');  /// call your funtion here ///
  
  var pathname2 = url.parse(req.url);
  console.log('pathname-1:'+pathname2);
  console.log('pathname-2:'+__dirname);
  console.log('pathname-3:'+__filename);
  console.log(url.parse(index));
  //console.log('basw path:'+process.env.PWD);
  res.sendFile(path.resolve('public/index.html'));
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
```

Comment: thanks for answer .but i confuse which url insert in`fs.readFile('./index.html'` and `$ = cheerio.load('file.html')`. som plz briefly explain. i try to without any other module solve my problem.

Comment: @Sumitpatel actually you don't need `cheerio.load('file.html')`. I have updated the answer. And if you don't want to use module then read the source code of [Cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) how they are doing.

Comment: if you don't mind .i can't understand this code which location put there `app.js` or `index.js(www/)`. so you can put my above code and update answer

Comment: @Sumitpatel I have updated the answer. If you still need help. We can continue in chat room

Comment: how to pass my index.html file because i don't know index.html path . my URL like that `/Tutorial/Routing/StateProvider/Setting/StudenList/StudenLis‌​t/2` then how to find my index.html file ?

Comment: Url is fine. But you must be serving the file from server.So you can directly access the file location (absolute path) in server. Still if problem the you can use `request` module for getting the 'page'  by passing the url.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132154/discussion-between-ricky-and-sumit-patel).